# Curve Fitting Error MATLAB in checkbounds function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, toolbox

I tried to run [one example code here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html)

```
x = linspace(1,100);  
y = 5 + 7*log(x);
myfittype = fittype('a + b*log(x)',...
    'dependent',{'y'},'independent',{'x'},...
    'coefficients',{'a','b'})
myfit = fit(x',y',myfittype)
```

I got the error message below

Error in checkbounds (line 26)

if lenlb > nvars

Error in fit>iFit (line 275)
[lowerbnd, upperbnd, anError, aWarning] = checkbounds( lowerbnd, upperbnd, numcoeff );

Error in fit (line 116)

[fitobj, goodness, output, convmsg] = iFit( xdatain, ydatain, fittypeobj, ...

[image: Code and error]
However, my code worked perfectly fine last night. I can't think of anything I did today that would possibly cause this problem.
I did change the path but now I set it to default and still got this problem. Any other possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is another checkbounds.m function and somehow MATLAB used the first one

I ran the code

```
which checkbounds -all
```

and got

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\toolbox\curvefit\curvefit\private\checkbounds.m  % Private to curvefit

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\toolbox\shared\optimlib\checkbounds.m

I have solved the problem by adding all the paths. I'm still not sure how MATLAB choose which checkbounds to run when there are many in the paths.

Comment: matlab path is ordered, meaning that it will use the first instance on top. Basically if you override a built-in function  it will always use yours because the path, being the latest to be added compared to the built-ins, will be on top